# NSDateFormatter : 12 hour formatted string can't converted in date when system date format is 24 hour in ios

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am working on app, which was completed successfully and becomes live. Now, I found a bug in that app, In that I am managing items with respect to user's current time. Like the time is defined with item available or not, and item will visible in that available time only. The time is sent with web service response with that item.

The format is like :

> "03:00 PM to 06:00 PM,06:30 PM to 07:30 PM"

And my current code is below to handle this :

```
BOOL isOkToProceed = NO;

    NSDate *today = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"server_date"];



    NSArray *spliteTimearr = [vendorTimeToday componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    //"03:00 PM to 06:00 PM,06:30 PM to 07:30 PM";
    for(int m=0;m<[spliteTimearr count];m++)
    {
        if([[spliteTimearr objectAtIndex:m] length] > 0)
        {
            NSArray *toSplitArr = [[spliteTimearr objectAtIndex:m] componentsSeparatedByString:@" to "];

            NSDateFormatter *inputDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
            [inputDateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];

            [inputDateFormatter setDefaultDate:today];
            //            [inputDateFormatter setDateFormat:[NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"hh:mm a" options:0 locale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_GB"]]];

            //[inputDateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
            //[inputDateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
            [inputDateFormatter setDoesRelativeDateFormatting:YES];


            NSDate *date1 = [inputDateFormatter dateFromString:[toSplitArr objectAtIndex:0]];

            NSDate *date2 = [inputDateFormatter dateFromString:[toSplitArr objectAtIndex:1]];

            if(([today isLaterThanOrEqualTo:date1]) && ([today isEarlierThanOrEqualTo:date2]))
            {
                isOkToProceed = YES;
                break;
            }

        }
    }

    return isOkToProceed;
```

This code works fine when my iPhone's date and time is in 12 hour format. But it return `nil` in `date1` and `date2` when iPhone's date and time format is 24 hour.

I have tried many options but didn't work. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `en_US_POSIX` locale when processing dates from the server (which should all be in UTC). See [this Apple tech note](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1480/_index.html) for details.